# How can I find the cubic polynomial, using $4\times4$ linear system with coefficients? Or any help of reference?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, binomial-coefficients

part A

in standard form $$y = a_0 + a_1t + a_2t^2 + a_3t^3$$ passes points  $$(0, 4), (1, 3), (−1, 7), (2, −2)$$
part B

and for the same cubic polynomial in shifted basis
$$\{1, t − 2,(t − 2)^2,(t − 2)^3\}$$
I'm not quite sure about using $4\times4$ linear system with coefficients.
Do I just solve it using coefficients like
$a+b(t-2)+c(t-2)^2+d(t-2)^2 = $  answer of first one?
Sorry about confusion, Part A is one question and part B is another, I guessed to solve Part B I have to use part A

Comment: "and for the same polynomial in shifted basis $\{1,\,t-2,\,(t-2)^2,\,(t-2)^2\}$" *what* happens?

Comment: In order for the curve to pass through the point (say) $(1,3)$, your equation $y=a_0 + a_1 t + a_2 t^2 + a_3 t^3$ must be true when $t=1$ and $y=3$; hence $a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + a_3 = 3$. If you do this with the other three points, you get a $4\times4$ system of linear equations. It will be invertible, and that will give you $a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3$. ... To answer your second question: Yes, because after you substitute for $t$, you'll get a linear equation there as well.

Comment: @Christopher Carl Heckman, Oh, so I put four points on standard form, I get the  $4×4$ system of linear equations! Thanks for your help sir :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but:

**Part A**:
Here, you can set up a linear system of equations to solve for the coefficients of the polynomial:
$$(0, 4) \implies a_0+a_1(0)+a_2(0)^2+a_3(0)^4=4$$
$$(1, 3) \implies a_0+a_1(1)+a_2(1)^2+a_3(1)^4=3$$
$$(-1, 7) \implies a_0+a_1(-1)+a_2(-1)^2+a_3(-1)^4=7$$
$$(2, -2) \implies a_0+a_1(2)+a_2(2)^2+a_3(2)^4=-2$$
Now that you have four linear equations and four variables, you can solve for $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3$ with any method of solving linear equations that you want to use.

**Part B**:
Once you have $a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2+a_3t^3$, you need to solve for $b_0+b_1(t-2)+b_2(t-2)^2+b_3(t-2)^3$. In order to make this easier, set $w=t-2$. We need to get the first polynomial from in terms of $t$ to in terms of $w$, so substitute $t=w+2$ into the first polynomial and expand in order to get the coefficients of $w$.

Comment: Um if i get the answer of Part A, do I have to solve Part B as that way? like if i get $a_0 = 0$, $a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = 2$, $a_3 = 3$, then like $b_0$+$b_1$(t-2)+$b_2$(t-2)^2+$b_3$(t-2)^3 = 0+t+2t^2+3t^3$. Isn't this work?

Comment: @Tot There are multiple ways to solve Part B. However, if you want to do it that way, once you have that equation, you need to plug in $t=0$, $t=1$, $t=-1$, and $t=2$ in order to get four linear equations in terms of $b_0, b_1, b_2, b_3$ and then solve another linear system. However, you should get the same answer both ways.

Comment: oh, that makes sense, let me try for these and thanks for your help sir :D